# How to deploy Spring Boot + gradle service on Openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

I've read tons of documentation and tutorials, but still cannot get through this.

I want to start developing a service using Spring boot and Gradle and deploy it on openshift.

With fabric8, there is a handy command `'mvn' clean install -Dfabric8.mode=openshift`
to run the deployment.
This uses maven tho, and I'm with Gradle.

How can I do it? I know that I need an s2i-builder, but I cannot understand how to use them.

I know that fabric8, uses `jboss-fuse-6/fis-java-openshift` as s2i build, I may want to use the same for my builds.

Also, I would like to know if there is a way to redeploy from local files (this should be called a binary deploy) for dev purposes. As last thing, the very next step for me is setting up Jenkins but to get started I just really want to know how to proceed.

---

I've this simple Dockerfile:

`FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-jar", "/app.jar"]`

I'm using this plugin: `"gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:0.13.0"` that gives me the Gradle task: `./gradlew build docker`.

This container gets built successfully, and if I run it locally with `docker run -p 8080:8080 it.example/microservice` it runs perfectly fine. Added this bit of content just because I feel I'm not too far.

Comment: Did you already try out https://learn.openshift.com/middleware/rhoar-getting-started-spring/?

Comment: Hello @MichaelHausenblas and thanks for the comment. Yeah, I've tried that already and it's very usefull - but uses fabric8 and maven exactly as I wrote in the post.